# Does the Iribarren criteria apply for tsunamis?

Tags: tsunami

The Iribarren number (slope ratio/√wave steepness) gives appearance of breaking waves. If the number is low, a spilling breaker occurs. If it is moderate, a spectacular plunger occurs. If it is large, a partially breaking or non breaking wave occurs.

But this number was developed for "normal" waves with steepness of, what, a few dozenths? Tsunamis can have steepness as low as in the thousandths. Does this criteria still accurately predict the appearance of a breaking tsunami?